# Multiple words in LIKE sql operator

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a variable str which contains a string like `The ruby` and it will find results based on that.

```
User.where('abc LIKE :q OR xyz LIKE :q ', q: "%#{str}%")
```

While it is working fine, I am stuck on what to do if the str variable contains an array like str = ["The", "ruby"]

I can run a loop but it will create multiple query and i dont want that. Can it be done in the same code ?

I know that if i have to test multiple words then i have to do something like this

```
User.where('abc LIKE :q OR abc LIKE :r OR xyz LIKE :q OR xyz LIKE :r ', q: "%#{str[0]}%", r: "%#{str[1]}%")
```

Just for example I have used 2 value in the array but in reality it could be of any length.

Please let me know if i am doing it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you initially thought, you could just do a loop to create multiple queries. You don't need to run the queries separately, however, you can join them doing into a single SQL statement using [`or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or):

```ruby
examples = ['The Ruby', ['The', 'Ruby']]

examples.each do |search|
  queries = Array(search).map do |search_term|
    User.where('category_title LIKE :q OR title LIKE :q OR description LIKE :q OR tag_list LIKE :q', q: "%#{search_term}%")
  end

  statement = queries.reduce do |statement, query|
    statement.or(query)
  end

  puts statement.to_sql
end
```

The output of that is (cleaned up a little, of course):

```sql
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
WHERE (category_title LIKE '%The Ruby%' OR title LIKE '%The Ruby%'
  OR description LIKE '%The Ruby%' OR tag_list LIKE '%The Ruby%')

SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
WHERE ((category_title LIKE '%The%' OR title LIKE '%The%' OR
          description LIKE '%The%' OR tag_list LIKE '%The%') OR
       (category_title LIKE '%Ruby%' OR title LIKE '%Ruby%' OR
          description LIKE '%Ruby%' OR tag_list LIKE '%Ruby%'))
```

Comment: it worked but is there a way to avoid doing multiple queries?

Comment: This will only execute a single query, if anything had been executed against the DB my script would've started yelling about everything because those columns don't exist on my user model.

Comment: sorry ya u are right.  I can see it only made one req.

Comment: can u please explain me how it made only one query? We are using the User.where inside the loop and would not that create multiple queries?

Comment: TL;DR rails doesn't perform the query until it needs the records for something; in the console this is immediately, because the console likes to show the output but in "real" code this is usually somewhere in the view, or wherever you are doing something with the records. It's the same thing as being able to do `User.where(...).where(...)`, you can call multiple `where` without triggering a query, so this is just storing that intermediary in a variable instead of immediately chaining it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is answer is deemed a bit off topic, but there are much more efficient ways to query for the information the OP's asking rather than by brute forcing this and chaining together lots of LIKE queries.

Which database engine are you using, @Raaz?  Multiple tokens sounds like a good use case for POSIX Regular Expression based queries.  Compared to a LIKE query, which only searches 1 token at a time, using Pattern matching would allow you to search any number of tokens in a single query with only a few WHERE clauses.

Both [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) can query using Patterns.

For Postgres, it would look something like this unproven code snippet:

```
Video.where("category_title SIMILAR TO '%(the|ruby)%'"
```

Another option which assumes you're using Postgres, is to use the [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem and perform a [multisearchable](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#multisearchable) search on your database.  You can query these four fields all at once and the database will do all the heavy lifting.  Again, this assumes you're using a Postgres database.

Comment: Sorry , I should have made it clear that I am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple query using ILIKE

```
str = ["The","Ruby"].map {|val| "%#{val}%" }

Video.where("category_title ILIKE ANY ( array[?] ) OR title ILIKE ANY (array[?] ) OR description ILIKE ANY (array[?] ) OR tag_list ILIKE ANY (array[?] )", str, str, str, str)
```

It's working for me.

Cheers!

Comment: Error
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE ANY ( array['%The%','%Ruby%'] ) OR title ILIKE ANY (array['%The%','%Ruby%'' at line 1: SELECT  `videos`.* FROM `videos` WHERE (category_title ILIKE ANY ( array['%The%','%Ruby%'] ) OR title ILIKE ANY (array['%The%','%Ruby%'] ) OR description ILIKE ANY (array['%The%','%Ruby%'] ) OR tag_list ILIKE ANY (array['%The%','%Ruby%'] )) LIMIT 11